# Regarding Hölder continuity

Tags: analysis, continuity, holder-spaces

> Let $\alpha \geq 0$. We say that $f \colon D \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is $\alpha$-Hölder continuous if there is a constant $c$ such that for each $x,x_0\in D$, $|f(x) - f(x_0)| \leqslant c\cdot |x - x_0|^{\alpha}.$
>
> Prove that if $D$ is bounded, $\alpha \leqslant \beta $, and $f$ is $\beta$-Hölder continuous, then $f$ is $\alpha$-Hölder continuous.

I know how to prove if there's only $\alpha$-Hölder continuity but not sure how to prove if $\beta$ comes in.

Comment: c can be anything.

Answer (score 1):

Write for any $x$ and $y$ in $D$ that $$|x-y|^{\beta}=|x-y|^{\alpha}\cdot |x-y|^{\beta-\alpha}\leqslant M\cdot |x-y|^\alpha,$$
where $M:=2^\alpha\sup_{s\in D}|s|^\alpha$.